# Best way to move data from one table to another SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have eight tables that I need to move data from one table to another for archive & data retention reasons. I am not the best at stored procedures so I am looking for ideas and best practices for moving data - even if it it means starting over from scratch. I'm sure I am doing something wrong but I am willing to learn.

My current T-SQL Code:

```
USE [SPCTST]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Insert_Data_Into_Archive_Tables]    Script Date: 5/10/2022 11:27:33 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO




/* =============================================
 Author:        Eric Brenner
 Create date:   3/3/2022
 Description:   Moves data from the ACTIVE tables
                to the ARCHIVE tables based on the 
                ARCHIVE_DATETIME below.

 Updates:       Added DELETE statement just after
                inserting records into the ARCHIVE
                tables.

 5/9/2022:      Removed EXCEPT clause, added
                seperate BEGIN and COMMIT
                clauses, and TRY statements.
 ============================================= */

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_Data_Into_Archive_Tables]
    --@Archive_Months tinyint -- Use this as a parameter if desired in the future. Currently disabled.
AS
    -- @ARCHIVE_DATETIME is a variable to contain the number of months worth of data you want to keep in the ARCHIVE table(s).
    DECLARE @ARCHIVE_DATETIME datetime = DATEADD(month, -26, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) -- a little over 2 years

    -- Convert Date to a 16-digit string to use against because of the db design
    DECLARE @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS nvarchar(16) = CONCAT(YEAR(@ARCHIVE_DATETIME), --year
                                FORMAT(@ARCHIVE_DATETIME,'MM'), --month
                                FORMAT(@ARCHIVE_DATETIME,'dd'), --day
                                '00000000')
    
    -- If the temporary table 'DateTimeValues' exists, remove it
    IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#DateTimeValues') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #DateTimeValues
    END
    
    -- Insert data into the Archive Tables
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                INSERT INTO OC_VNOTE_ARCHIVE
                    SELECT * FROM OC_VNOTE WHERE OC_VNOTE.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                DELETE FROM OC_VNOTE WHERE OC_VNOTE.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH
    END

    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                INSERT INTO OC_VMON_AUX_ARCHIVE
                    SELECT * FROM OC_VMON_AUX WHERE OC_VMON_AUX.DATETIMEAUX < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                DELETE FROM OC_VMON_AUX WHERE OC_VMON_AUX.DATETIMEAUX < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH
    END

    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                INSERT INTO OC_VMON_ARCHIVE
                    SELECT * FROM OC_VMON WHERE OC_VMON.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                DELETE FROM OC_VMON WHERE OC_VMON.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH
    END

    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                INSERT INTO OC_VDAT_AUX_ARCHIVE
                    SELECT * FROM OC_VDAT_AUX WHERE OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                DELETE FROM OC_VDAT_AUX WHERE OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH
    END

    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                INSERT INTO OC_VDATA_ARCHIVE
                    SELECT * FROM OC_VDATA WHERE OC_VDATA.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                DELETE FROM OC_VDATA WHERE OC_VDATA.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH
    END

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                INSERT INTO OC_DNOTE_ARCHIVE_PC
                    SELECT * FROM OC_DNOTE_PC WHERE OC_DNOTE_PC.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                DELETE FROM OC_DNOTE_PC WHERE OC_DNOTE_PC.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH
    END

    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                INSERT INTO OC_DDAT_AUX_ARCHIVE_PC
                    SELECT * FROM OC_DDAT_AUX_PC WHERE OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.DATETIMEAUX < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                DELETE FROM OC_DDAT_AUX_PC WHERE OC_DDAT_AUX_PC.DATETIMEAUX < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH
    END

    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                INSERT INTO OC_DDATA_ARCHIVE_PC
                    SELECT * FROM OC_DDATA_PC WHERE OC_DDATA_PC.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                DELETE FROM OC_DDATA_PC WHERE OC_DDATA_PC.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH
    END

GO
```

Comment: do you mean automatically like replication or manually?

Comment: Minimally each INSERT/DELETE pair should be in the same transaction.

Comment: `DATEADD(month, -26, DATEADD(mm,` Learn to write code consistently. You used the full part name first and then used the abbreviation - why? Don't use the abbreviations. That is trivial effort to type and makes your code more difficult to read. Use terminators for EVERY statement. Why use datetime when you are only concerned about date? And you can  cast a datetime value to date and "lose" the time portion. Don't use that kludge involving zero and datediff. Lastly, don't use "*" as a column list and specify the column list for an INSERT statement. That's a start at better coding.

Comment: I would consider batching and using the OUTPUT syntax of a delete https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/12/how-to-batch-updates-a-few-thousand-rows-at-a-time/ and https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-insert-and-delete-statements

Comment: @Andrew That's ultimately what needs to happen because there could be 1000s of records that need to be moved (if not close to 1,000,000).

Comment: @SMor Thank you for your insight. I'll take your suggestions and apply them. I think I need to go smaller scale first (meaning, focus just on one table in my test db) and see if I can get this working the way I want. I'll surely revisit this.

Comment: You may wish to consider your reasons for archiving - is this for performance? It's often a better idea to address performance with partitioning, indexes, compression, SQL optimisation rather than moving data to a physically seperate table

Answer (score 1):

**First** you do not need to have all those TRY CATCH in your code. Only one will be sufficient with this code :

```
BEGIN CATCH
   IF XACT_STATE()<> 0
      ROLLBACK;
   THROW;
END CATCH
```

**Second**, you can use partition to switch sets of rows from one table to another by a simple "SWITCH PARTITION ... " command that will act on all your table is they have the same partition parameter (which seems to be the case with the DTATIME column...

**Third** you can do a transaction on each couple of INSERT/DELETE to minimize the transaction log growth

Comment: I need to also consider batching because of the records I'll need to move. It's a monthly update so I don't want my users being locked out of the table as they are trying to add new data to the table.

Comment: SWITCH PARTITION is a great way to deal with table locks. So is RCSI

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in one go. Set the database in simple recovery mode, if possible; keep batches small to avoid growth of the logfile.
This code will roll back completely in case of failure:

```
DELETE FROM OC_VNOTE 
OUTPUT deleted.*
INTO OC_VNOTE_ARCHIVE
WHERE OC_VNOTE.DATETIME < @ARCHIVE_DATETIME_GS;
```